# How can I disable a navbar link after I push a button and successfully redirect to another page?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, .net, asp.net-core

I'm working on a project and I need to disable a navbar link after I push a button that redirects me to another page if the post request was successful.

How can I have access to the navbar link, do I need to use css selectors, I'm planning to on using jquery to disable it, but I don't know how can I select it from another file, because my script is in my Index.html, and I have to have access to the _Navbar.html

//This is my _Navbar.html page. I want to disable the Contact page after a button has been pressed.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">                   
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>                   
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a asp-page="/Index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

//I tried to css selectors from the Index.html, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _Navbar.html content is part of the DOM so you should be able to access it from a script, regardless of which file it is called from.

The link items don't have unique IDs - in theory you could look for the nth-child of 'navbar-nav' if 'Contact' is always going to be in a consistent position, but that is an anti-pattern that will give you a headache in the future if it ever moves.

The easy solution, give each link item an ID, and you can select and hide as needed.